# Finding a Function Address to Call when Functions Are Not Exported

Tags: c, windows, hex, portable-executable

On Windows, I know if the function is not exported you can always scan the DLL or PE for a specific string of bytes to get the address.

Now my question is how can you find those functions in a hex editor, so I can use the adjacent bytes to scan and get the function address?

Comment: Q: have you tried GetProcAddress()?  Or dumpbin.exe?

Comment: GetProcAddress only works if the functions are exported.  I need to use non-exported functions and to get the address you have to calculate the address in the DLL somehow.  Usually by byte scanning.

Comment: "how can you find those functions in a hex editor"?  You can't.  You'll need to use a disassembler, and even then it's likely to be impractical, although this depends to some extent on how much you already know about the code.  If you don't have the source code, how do you even know what functions exist?  (Note that if you do have the source code, rebuilding it and exporting the relevant functions will almost always be both easier and more reliable than your approach.)

Comment: in linux for this very purpose I use dlsym(). never used windows.

Comment: If the function isn't exported you don't have any guarantee that it exists anymore "in function form" - e.g. the compiler may have inlined it everywhere and the linker found out that the "freestanding version" could be dropped altogether.

Comment: Anything you do here will be very fragile and can easily break if a new version of the DLL gets released.  Tread very carefully here, and do try to see if there's an alternative, supported way of doing what you want.